# How to simulate the 'ENTER' keypress in cmd?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to find a way to imitate a keypress in cmd in this function:

```
start cmd.exe /k
```

so that it would just start cmd, jump a line (simulating hitting the 'enter' key) and then doing something. Can anybody help me?

Just to make it more understandable, I want to simulate the ENTER keypress itself, not just adding a newline. My scenario is that I want to open a file/application that has a buffer on startup that can be skipped by pressing ENTER (similar to the startup on windows Ubuntu where if you are starting it using the "start ubuntu.exe /k (something)" command, it will immediately close if you try to run a command but will skip the beginning startup if the ENTER key is pressed.

Comment: Feed it a file with a blank line. `Start` in not how you start programs. Type `start /?` to learn how to start programs.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance Mark but can you explain to me what that means? I'm sorry, I don't understand your suggestion.

Comment: I'm kinda stupid sorry...

Comment: Open a command prompt, type `start /?` and hit Enter.

Comment: See https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/12/command-prompt-cheat-sheet.html for an overview of using command prompt.

Comment: reposting an exact duplicate, because the original question was closed as unclear is not how it works here. The initial question was closed as unclear for a reason.

Answer (score 3):

Cmd does not support sending interactive keys to sessions.

That said, some commands will take pipped input which can get around this limitation.  But that is by no means a guarantee.

To test try this, don't bother with the start cmd stuff for now, just see if it is even possible:

```
ECHO=|ubuntu.exe /k (something)
```

If that woeka you can work with opening a separate command window, if not then likely its not possible without researching the Ubuntu command to see if a command line option allows you to skip the portion you want to or not.

Comment: That works but I can't put it in a start command it doesn't work